# Replace All URLs within DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to amend all URLs within a specified DIV but unsure how to.  An example I want is:

```
<div id="SearchList">
<a href="www.google.com/up">up</a>
<a href="www.google.com/down">down</a>
<a href="www.google.com/left">left</a>
<a href="www.google.com/right">right</a>
</div>
```

So for example I would like to amend the URLs to be displayed as follows:

```
<div id="SearchList">
<a href="www.bing.com/up">up</a>
<a href="www.bing.com/down">down</a>
<a href="www.bing.com/left">left</a>
<a href="www.bing.com/right">right</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Lots. Why don't you try it and we'll see if they match?

Comment: Better ask than try uh?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what isn't working for you? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// For each anchor element...
$("#SearchList a").each(function() { 

    // Change its 'href' attribute to...
    $(this).attr("href", 

        // Its current 'href' attribute with a .replace() called
        $(this).attr("href").replace("google", "bing")); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do

```
$('#SearchList a').each(function(){

    var $el = $(this),
        hash = $el.attr('href'),
        replace = 'www.bing.com',
        regex = /www.+.com\//,
        replacement = hash.replace(regex, replace);

    $el.attr('href', replacement);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter would be

```
$('a').prop('href', function(i,e){ return e.replace('google', 'bing')});
```